# Creating objects with cypher using neo4j ogm

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I have started using neo4j-ogm `2.1.0` and I have a basic question.

I understand that we can persist or query objects to/from a graph with a fixed, declarative domain model.

My requirement is to do this using cypher instead, so that I don't have to worry about dynamic types which may not be declared in my domain model. I have already referred to 
[Neo4j-Ogm for dynamic domain object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956078/neo4j-ogm-for-dynamic-domain-object-model).

My question is, can I do something like:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
String cypher = "CREATE (n:MyNode{name:"my name"}) RETURN n";
try {
    session.execute(cypher);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about modelling domain objects and simply want an API to execute Cypher statements from Java then you can either use the [Bolt Driver](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-java-driver) (requires Neo4j 3.0 and above; refer to the manual for usage) or by using the HTTP Endpoint with a client ([like this one](https://github.com/inner-loop/java-neo4j-client)).

If you want a mix of both then you can continue to use the Neo4j OGM and just call the `query` or `queryForObject` methods on `Session` to call your dynamic cypher.